# 555 timer output current

Tags: circuit-analysis, 555

I'm designing a 555 timer circuit where I want to control the brightness of an LED array. There is a minimum lux requirement for the array so I need to know the output current when I have a 4.8 V source.

[image]

This is a similar diagram. The only difference is I have a 4.8 V source and an LED array instead of an LED.

Without the 555 chip (simple circuit with 7 LEDs and resistors connected in parallel) I have about 140mA current going to the array. I would like to know if the values of resistor and potentiometer at pins 6 and 7 will affect the output current. I don't have tools to measure lux so my only guidance is 140mA current output.

Thanks.

Comment: Well there are a lot of 555s to choose from, I am pretty sure at least one of them can source 140mA, head on over the Digikey or where ever, maybe a TI SE555.

Comment: Answer should be in the data sheet. Question should be closed.

Comment: While the answer you've chosen is correct, your schematic is not a great idea. The LEDs should have current limiting resistors, and the 555 output will not drive full current at full voltage. The NE555, for instance, with a 5 volt supply, is only guaranteed to put out 3 volts with a 100 mA current.

Comment: I bought some capacitors and tested the circuit with and without the resistor. I can't see the flashing LED with the resistor. I removed the resistor and the LED is now blinking and its frequency determined by the potentiometer. I know this isn't a good practice as you said.

Comment: Why do you have resistors in *parallel* with LEDs?

Comment: Resistors are connected in series with the leds. 7 LEDs, each drawing 20mA, are connected in parallel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current coming out of pin 3 is not affected in any way by whatever current may be flowing into or out of pins 6 and 7. Pin 3 is essentially the output of an S-R latch, which draws it's output current from the voltage rail in parallel with the comparators.